# 2 VMware Fusion VMs: One hosting application, other one accessing it, host not involved

Tags: networking, vmware-fusion

been searching around and haven't been able to find an answer for between two VMs (and what I've tried hasn't worked).

*Pardon the 'url' pretend it's 'http://' (can't post more than 2 links)*

Both VMs are running on NAT (Share with Mac)
One VM is Windows Server 2012 RS, other is CentOs
CentOS is hosting a tomcat server
I want to be able to access that server (123.456.789.012) from the windows server (eg: url 123.456.789.012:1802).

I've tried grabbing the IP off ifconfig from the centOS box:

```
eno16777736: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.16.170.128  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.16.170.255
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe11:e2d3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 00:0c:29:11:e2:d3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 520378  bytes 594579006 (567.0 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 237299  bytes 30535626 (29.1 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, from the windows vm trying: url 172.16.170.128:1802 but get nothing. It's pingable. From the centOS VM I can see the server up and running at:url localhost:1802

I'm probably missing something very simple, but I'm usually really horrible at networking stuff. Do I have to do something through the host (mac)?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears I just had to add it to the hosts file on the Windows VM. Still don't know why it wasn't working straight with the IP, but it seemed to be bringing in the other additions from my hosts file on the server machine when I would type in just the IP.